# QGIS crashes when trying to make heatmap

Tags: qgis, mac, heat-map

I'm a new user of QGIS. I need to make a heatmap for my thesis and I'm fairly certain I downloaded and set up the program correctly via online instructions. I imported the GDX points and used a Google Earth basemap and selected the heatmap plugin. After selecting the options I wanted (I'm new at heatmaps, maybe I wasn't doing something right), I clicked ok and the whole program crashed. I'm using a MacBook Pro running OSX Yosemite.

Here is a link to the crash log: http://pastebin.com/sTyxXZ0Q

[image: This is a screenshot of the heatmap plugin options. I'm just playing around with the settings because I'm new at this. No matter what I seem to choose, it crashes.]

Comment: You can try to post the error at http://pastebin.com/ or something similar and update/edit your question with the link.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: I cannot find any usable info in the error unfortunately. Can you provide the settings you used in the heatmap tool? A screenshot would be good

Comment: Ok I added one. I just was using the default settings and chose a radius of 2,000 meters because my study area was about that large. I'm not sure of advanced settings.

Comment: I'd suggest reprojecting the points to EPSG:3857 or an local CRS before trying to compute the heatmap.

Comment: It still crashed. :( I'm really at a loss here. There must be something wrong with the program. I downloaded everything it said to download.